# Trying to isolate all columns (representing years) via conditional operator and renaming them in R

Tags: r, database, select, dataset

```
library(readr)

d <- read.csv("per_capita.csv")

rc <- d[,-2:-3]


df <- data.frame(rc)

draw <- df$X1994[df$Country.Name == "India"]

format(draw, scientific = F, big.marks = ",")

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(Country.Name == "India") %>%
  select(names(.)[-1][readr::parse_integer(names(.)[-1] > 1994])
```

I tried this code and its giving me an error in the last line. Also, how should I rename these columns in the CSV file without using a dataframe?

The column names are: X1994, X1995..... and so on.

Thank You!

Comment: Use include a sample of your data for us to see and work with. You can use `dput(head(df))` and it will give us 5-rows

Comment: `
> dput(head(dat))
structure(list(Country.Name = c("Aruba", "Africa Eastern and Southern", 
"Afghanistan", "Africa Western and Central", "Angola", "Albania"
), X1990 = c(1363755808.78007, 561920280331.289, NA, 354292026911.973, 
38665241764.817, 8379725523.57465), X1991 = c(1522141309.42665, 
581615642052.174, NA, 370718366510.069, 40369082197.805, 6237252125.20748.

`

Comment: Column names are- 'Country.Name', 'X1990',...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select columns that have numbers greater than a value, you could do this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

#example
set.seed(24)
df <- tibble(country = rep(c("India", "Canada"), each = 3),
       X1990 = runif(6),
       X1991 = runif(6),
       X1992 = runif(6))

df |>
  filter(country == "India")  |>
  select(!!!vars(colnames(df)[-1][which(parse_number(colnames(df)[-1]) > 1990)]))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   X1991 X1992
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.280 0.672
#> 2 0.764 0.673
#> 3 0.802 0.320
```

Although that is pretty complicated. It might be better to go long, filter, then go wide:

```r
df |>
  filter(country == "India") |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(contains("X")) |>
  mutate(name = parse_number(name))|>
  filter(name > 1990) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)|>
  select(-c(id, country))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   `1991` `1992`
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  0.280  0.672
#> 2  0.764  0.673
#> 3  0.802  0.320
```

We can see that this answer is pretty long and cumbersome. Maybe we stick in base R:

```r
cols <- which(as.numeric(sub("^.*?(\\d+).*$", "\\1", colnames(df)[-1])) > 1990) +1
rows <- df$country == "India"

df[rows,cols]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   X1991 X1992
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.280 0.672
#> 2 0.764 0.673
#> 3 0.802 0.320
```

Or actually, maybe we can make the `tidyverse` version cleaner if we just look for strings that have values higher than the target year:

```r
all_years <- 1990:1995

df |>
  filter(country == "India") |>
  select(contains(paste0("X", all_years[all_years > 1990])))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   X1991 X1992
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.280 0.672
#> 2 0.764 0.673
#> 3 0.802 0.320
```

Using the same logic, we can also do a partial string match with base R:

```r
all_years <- 1990:1995

cols <- grepl(paste(all_years[all_years>1990], collapse = "|"), colnames(df))
rows <- df$country == "India"

df[rows,cols]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   X1991 X1992
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.280 0.672
#> 2 0.764 0.673
#> 3 0.802 0.320
```

Hopefully one of these helps and strikes your fancy. Lots of options out there for whatever flavor your in the mood for.